# Why a range_iterator when a range is reversed?

Tags: python-3.x, range

I can subscript a `range` object:

```
>>> r = range(4)
>>> r 
range(0, 4)
>>> r[3]
3
>>> for i in r:
    print(i)

0
1
2
3
>>> list(r)
[0, 1, 2, 3]
```

But, if I call `reversed` on the same `range` object:

```
>>> r = reversed(range(4))
>>> r
<range_iterator object at memaddr>
>>> for i in r:
    print(i)
3
2
1
0
>>> r[3]
TypeError: 'range_iterator' object is not subscriptable         # ?
>>> range(r)
TypeError: 'range_iterator' cannot be interpreted as an integer # ?
>>> list(r)
[]          # ? uhmm
```

Hmm... Acting kinda like a generator but less useful.

Is there a reason a reversed range object isn't like a normal generator / iterator in how it quacks?

Comment: generator / iterator, you can only loop once and its gone.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `reversed` function returns an iterator, not a sequence. That's just how it's designed. The `range_iterator` you're seeing is essentially `iter` called on the reversed `range` you seem to want.

To get the reversed sequence rather than a reverse iterator, use the "alien smiley" slice: `r[::-1]` (where `r` is the value you got from `range`). This works both in Python 2 (where `range` returns a list) and in Python 3 (where `range` returns a sequence-like `range` object).

Answer (score 9):

You need to change `r` back to a `list` type. For example:

```
reversed([1,2]) #prints <listreverseiterator object at 0x10a0039d0>
list(reversed([1,2])) #prints [2,1]
```

---

### Edit

To clarify what you are asking, here is some sample I/O:

```
>>> r = range(5)
>>> x = reversed(r)
>>> print x
<listreverseiterator object at 0x10b6cea90>
>>> x[2]

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#24>", line 1, in <module>
    x[2]
TypeError: 'listreverseiterator' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
>>> x = list(x)
>>> x[2] #it works here
2
```

Comment: `TypeError: 'list_reverseiterator' object is not subscriptable`. This doesn't really answer the question, because this requires `reversed(list(range(4)))`.