# Why does conversion of a range object to generator result in a `range_iterator` object?

Tags: python, generator

This is not a duplicate of [Why a range_iterator when a range is reversed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35834210/why-a-range-iterator-when-a-range-is-reversed) You'll know why if you take a look at it.

My question pertains to the distinction between a generator resulting from `range` versus any other iterator, and why that distinction is made:

```
In [500]: iter(range(5))
Out[500]: <range_iterator at 0x10987f810>
```

Whereas...

```
In [506]: (i for i in range(4))
Out[506]: <generator object <genexpr> at 0x10a025fc0>
```

So, why is this distinction made and what merit does it have?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simple, `range` is not an iterator:

```
In [32]: r = range(10)

In [33]: next(r)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-33-0b5056469c9c> in <module>()
----> 1 next(r)

TypeError: 'range' object is not an iterator
```

`range` is a sequence type, and like all other containers, `iter` returns a corresponding iterator object:

```
In [34]: iter(list())
Out[34]: <list_iterator at 0x112197cc0>

In [35]: iter(tuple())
Out[35]: <tuple_iterator at 0x112107be0>

In [36]: iter(dict())
Out[36]: <dict_keyiterator at 0x1142eef98>
```

Generally, containers are *iterables*, not *iterators*. They implement `__iter__`, whereas an iterator implements `__iter__` **and** `__next__`.

Note, the terminology in your title is a bit off, and frankly, I think you are conflating generators, iterators, and iterables. `iter(obj)` doesn't return a *generator*, it returns an *iterator* object. A generator is a language construct that allows for succinctly writing iterators. The `generator` objects returned by a generator function *are* iterators:

```
In [37]: def mygen():
    ...:     yield 1
    ...:     yield 2
    ...:

In [38]: g = mygen()

In [39]: g
Out[39]: <generator object mygen at 0x1121778e0>

In [40]: next(g)
Out[40]: 1

In [41]: iter(g) is g
Out[41]: True
```

Finally, a generator expression is just an even handier way of writing generators!

```
In [44]: (i for i in range(10) if i % 2 == 0)
Out[44]: <generator object <genexpr> at 0x10de89990>

In [45]: next(_)
Out[45]: 0
```

Comment: So the `__repr__` only serves to help identify the source of the generator?

Comment: Thank you, this makes sense.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Yep. Just keep in mind the distinctions between generators, iterables, iterators, and containers. `range` is a container (a sequence) that is iterable.